# Digest authentication for HTTP requests in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, digest-authentication

Microsoft Power Automate does not provide digest authentication for HTTP requests out of the box.

However, to access an API with Power Automate, we need Digest Authentication. Has anyone ever implemented this and can give me some tips?

Comment: Can you provide the endpoint?  I don't need creds, I'd just like to confirm something.

Comment: No, I can't, but you can use http://httpbin.org/#/Auth for testing.